# Unblock virtual smart card

Tags: windows, certificate, login, smartcard

I've setup a virtual smart card by following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/virtual-smart-cards/virtual-smart-card-get-started#step-2-create-the-tpm-virtual-smart-card). It worked fine until someone locked out the virtual smart card and now it's blocked.

When I try to use it with the correct code to sign in to the computer it says:

> The security device cannot process the PIN. The PIN has been blocked
> temporarily because too many incorrect PINs have been entered. Try
> again later. If this message reoccurs, contact your administrator to
> reset the lockout period for this security device. Please contact your
> administrator for instructions on how to unblock your security device.

When I click on ok, I am now prompted with a screen with 3 fields, Response, New PIN and Confirm PIN, above those it says:

> Please contact your administrator for instructions on how to unblock
> your security device.

Now, I am one of the admins myself and I know that vendors of different smart cards use what's called a response calculator to unblock the smart card. But from hours of googling, there doesn't seem to exist something like this for a virtual smart card. There also doesn't seem to be a way to use the PUK to unlock it.

Some sites also suggest that after a certain time period it should unlock itself but it's now almost 3 days since it's been blocked and it hasn't unblocked itself yet.

I think that I could reset the TPM chip which I guess would then enable me to re-create the whole smart card and request new certs but I would prefer not to do this at this point since this would also wreck the Bitlocker (which is enabled on the C: drive).

Does anybody know how to unblock a virtual smart card?

Comment: FYI Virtual Smart Cards will be deprecated in the near future. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/virtual-smart-cards/virtual-smart-card-overview